# Sidebar and Button - with last version OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, button

I have a code with OpenLayers v4 with a sidebar component, according to https://turbo87.github.io/sidebar-v2/examples/ol3.html#home, working correctly.
However, I needed to change to the most current version of OpenLayers, and my code stopped working.

[CODE JS]

```
var sidebar = new ol.control.Sidebar({
    element: 'sidebar',
    position: 'left'
});

 // add layer switcher in sidebar   
var toc = document.getElementById('layers');
ol.control.LayerSwitcher.renderPanel(map, toc, { reverse: false });
map.addControl(sidebar);
```

Does anyone know how to resolve?

Note, in the example code https://turbo87.github.io/sidebar-v2/examples/ol3.html#home is also no longer opening the panel, when you click on a sidebar item.

[RESOLVED SIDEBAR]

https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2/issues/321

https://raw.githack.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher/master/examples/sidebar.html

I'm encountering the same problem with several controls, including Button, which was working in another version. In Openlayers 7 version, my code below doesn't work

[CODE JS]

```
var my_button = new ol.control.Button({
    html: '<i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>',
    title: "Zoom in",
    handleClick: function() {
            //here
    }
});
```

Comment: Try this: http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/control/map.control.overlay.menu.html

Comment: The example is not working because the link to ol.js it uses is not valid.  No extensions written for earlier versions of OpenLayers will work with OpenLayers 7.  If you need an updated version of ol-siidebar which works with OL7 you can get it from the link in https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2/issues/321

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that link.

Comment: @Mike,thanks. I got it using this link. Follow to share the example using the new files [link](https://raw.githack.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher/master/examples/sidebar.html).